# Front derailleur won’t shift into third gear

Tags: derailleur-front

Total mechanical noob here so I appreciate your help and patience. Have a Mid 2000’s Giant Sedona Cx. The front derailleur won’t shift into third gear.

I have tried a few things to see what’s going on. I’ve attempted tightening the shifter cable, adjusting the high limit screw as well as adjusting the derailleur on the frame. All with no luck.

When attempting to shift into third, the shifter doesn’t seem to engage the derailleur until it is pressed at least 75% of the way down. When pressed all the way down the derailleur isn’t pushed far enough to even contact the chain yet alone push it up to the third gear.

Given this information I suspect the shifter may need to be replaced. I’d just like a better opinion before I go any further. Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you manually pull on the derailleur cable, can you get the derailleur to move over all three gears?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. On your suggestion I manually pulled the derailleur cable. This pushed the derailleur a few mm closer to the chain, but still not enough to move into third. After that, I tried moving the derailleur on the frame again, doing this I was able to put it into a position where it will push into third. However it now won’t go back into first, while on the first gear on the shifter it’s on 2nd gear, and on 2nd it‘s on the largest cog. Suspecting a shifter issue here.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't reply all weekend.  If the derailleur doesn't have enough range for all the gears when you manually pull the cable, and the cable has no tension when it is at one end of its range, then the problem sounds to me like a derailleur problem, like a limit screw.  [Park Tool's web page on front derailleur adjustment](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment) explains much better than I could.  Good luck!